# How to add route value to actionLink if page is usig DataTable as a model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatable, dataset

I am working on simple database project. I need to use actionLink for mapping different action. I having trouble with passing route values.

Index action method:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index() {

            DataSet dt = new DataSet();

            using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
                sqlcon.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT CarInformation.ID,CarInformation.BRAND,CarInformation.OWNER_ID,CarInformation.PRICE,CarInformation.AVALIABLE_DAYS FROM CarInformation WHERE CarInformation.BRAND=(SELECT TOP 1 BRAND FROM Request ORDER BY REQUEST_ID DESC) AND (SELECT TOP 1 WISH FROM Request ORDER BY REQUEST_ID DESC)<=CarInformation.AVALIABLE_DAYS AND CarInformation.PRICE<=(SELECT TOP 1 PRICE FROM Request ORDER BY REQUEST_ID DESC)", sqlcon);
                sqlDa.Fill(dt, "CarInformation");
            }

            return View(dt.Tables["CarInformation"]);
        }
```

Corresponding index action view that cointain actionLink:

```
@model System.Data.DataTable

table class="table table-bordered table-striped table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
            {
                <th>@col.Caption</th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in Model.Rows)
        {
            <tr>
                @foreach (var cell in row.ItemArray)
                {
                    <td>@cell.ToString()</td>

                }
                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Click to rent", "IntoSaleTable",new {id= ,price=,})</td>
            </tr>

        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Mapped action:

```
public ActionResult IntoSaleTable(int id, int price) {
.
.
.

}
```

Index method provides me printing query results on screen.
What I need to do is getting "id " and "price" column of this output [1]

[1]https://imgur.com/Y0JERLa

Comment: You have a DataRow so use :  row["PRICE"] and row["ID"]

Comment: @jdweng  you mean new{id=row["ID"],price=row[''PRICE'']} right? Do I need to indicate as a new ?

Comment: Your statement is showing how to put the two objects into a linq an anonymous object.  Your posting has the two variables as separate parameters being passed in to the method IntoSaleTable(int id, int price).

Comment: @jdweng. Thank you! Your advice solved my problem.